# Inward Curve in React native

Tags: react-native

This is what i want to make in react native. There is a shadow for the whole card (including the curve at the middle).

[image]

Does someone have a solution?

Comment: Kindly post a screenshot showing your design.

Answer (score 0):

draw 2 circles in left and right part of the white box and give it a `flexDirection: 'row'`; like the example below:

```
return(
  <View style={{
flexDirection: 'row',
backgroundColor: 'white',
shadowColor: "#000",
shadowOffset: {
    width: 0,
    height: 2,
},
shadowOpacity: 0.25,
shadowRadius: 3.84,

elevation: 5
 }}>
     {/* circle */}
     <View style={{width: 20, height: 20, borderRadius: 10, backgroundColor: 'blue' }}/> 
     <View style={{width: '80%', height: 60}}>
         {/* your box info here */}
     </View>
     { /*circle */}
     <View style={{width: 20, height: 20, borderRadius: 10,backgroundColor: 'blue' }}/>
  </View>
)
```